# How to remove parent entity without removing child?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities.

```
@Entity
class Parent(){
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    
    private String someValue;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Child child;
}

@Entity
class Child(){
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    
    private String someVariable;
    
    private Integer someValue;
}
```

And when i remove Parent entity - the child entity removed automatically.
How can I delete a parent without deleting the child?

Comment: Don't cascade all, exclude at least REMOVE. Not the case here as its false by default for this annotation, but have a look at the orphanRemoval property of `@OneToOne`.

Comment: @KenS by default, orphanRemoval value is "false". But when i try to remove the paren entity - child entity is also removed

Comment: The main point was the first sentence. See the answer by Harry_T. The part about orphanRemoval was just a side note as that can be an issue with other mappings where it is in fact by default "true".

Comment: please, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459248/why-is-hibernate-trying-to-find-an-entity-in-the-database-instead-of-creating-it?noredirect=1#comment115731070_65459248

Answer (score 1):

The are many `CascadeType` (PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, ...). The annotation line `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` supposes that you are combining all of the cascadeType. The `CascadeType.REMOVE` will remove all related children of the current row when removing. To avoid this, just change your cascade type to following `@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the cascade, in your code, is `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`,which means all below operations will cascade.

You can try this, `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST`
that will only cascade when you persist an entity, also, other types are available if you want:`MERGE, REFRESH, REMOVE, DETACH`.

For more official info, refer to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/binding/CascadeType.html

Comment: When i use `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST` then hibernate tries to find the child entity in the database instead of creating it and threw EntityNotFoundException when `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST`

Comment: EntityNotFound occurs in many cases, like optional="false", or merging a PARENT entity but not cascade merge operation for CHILD entity. Please give more infos like error stacktrace and invoked code block for better clearing the question.