# Why is hibernate trying to find an entity in the database instead of creating it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    
    private String someValue;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Child child;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    
    private String someVariable;
    
    private Integer someValue;
}
```

And the entity persistence logic is pretty simple:

```
@Override
public ParentDto create(ParentDto parentDto) {
    if (repository.existsById(parentDto.getId())){
        throw new ParentWithIdAlreadyExistsException(parentDto.getId());
    }
    return mapper.toDto(repository.save(mapper.toDomain(parentDto)));
}
```

But when i try to persist the Parent entity - hibernate throw exception

> nested exception is
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable
> to find .child with id
> 6d387565-0e7c-4b0d-85ba-c21cdbb39871; nested exception is
> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find
> .Child with id 6d387565-0e7c-4b0d-85ba-c21cdbb39871] with
> root cause

Why is hibernate trying to find the Child entity in the database instead of creating it?

Comment: We can make a conclusion that `Parent.id` should be equal to `Child.id`. So, why do you use `@GeneratedValue` for `Child`? I guess it should be removed. Please show how do you persist the entities.

Comment: I updated my question. Look above

Comment: Please show also `mapper.toDomain` method.

Answer (score 0):

There were typo in your class names. Classname cannot start with `brackets ()`.